# htaccess, How to redirect one directory to one file, another directory to other file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have problems using htaccess in WAMP. I need to do the following:

1) redirect URLs like http://localhost/movie_questions/some_number/... to the file http://localhost/movie_questions.php

2) redirect URLs like http://localhost/movie_quiz/some_number/... to the file http://localhost/movie_quiz.php.

3) It's preferable that URLs in rewrite url rules be relative, because I later plan migrating to an Internet server.

Directories 'movie_questions' and 'movie_quiz' do not exist on my server.
Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /movie_questions/(.*) /movie_questions.php
RewriteRule /movie_quiz/(.*) /movie_quiz.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Instead of redirecting, I get 404.

Comment: If you get 404 you a redirecting to a wrong file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the leading slash from your RewriteRule's pattern

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^movie_question/(.*)$ /movie_question.php [L]
RewriteRule ^movie_quiz/(.*)$ /movie_quiz.php [L]
```